# Change of variable for conditional probability

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability, change-of-variable

Suppose I have random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, with $Z \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and $Y = kX + Z$, I am looking for a proof of the fact that$$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid X = x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} \exp\left(\frac{-(y-kx)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right).$$

The only definition that I am aware for conditional distribution is that $$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid X = x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f(x)}$$ and it is not obvious at all how the conclusion should follow from this definition. I suppose one should use some sort of change of variable formula.

Some updates:

I am asking this only because this formula is constantly used in statistics, for instance, it is used in section 3 probabilistic interpretation of [this notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes2020spring/cs229-notes1.pdf). But I feel quite confused about the way it is used and have no idea how it will follow naturally from the definition.

Comment: It is impossible to prove such a thing without additional assumptions such as independence.

Comment: Also the notation '$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid X = x)$' is non-standard.

Comment: Isn't this used in the formulation of the maximum likelihood? See section three of http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes2020spring/cs229-notes1.pdf for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty different approach but same result.

It is understood that independence between X an Y is to be assumed.

$$Z=Y-kX \sim N(0;\sigma^2)$$

$$\frac{Z}{\sigma}=\frac{Y-kX}{\sigma} \sim \Phi$$

Given a fixed $X=x$ we have

$$\frac{Y-kx}{\sigma} \sim \Phi$$

this is enough to show that $Y|X=x \sim N(kx;\sigma^2)$, that means

$f_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y-kx)^2}  $

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 3):

We assume that $X$ and $Z$ are independent. This is a common assumption in machine learning that we assume the noise $Z$ and the data $X$ are independent

If $X$ is known to take constant value $x$, then

\begin{align}
Pr(Y\le y|X=x) &= Pr(kX+Z \le y|X=x) \\
&= Pr(Z \le y-kx|X=x)\\
&= Pr(Z \le y-kx) \text{, by independence}\\
&= Pr\left( \frac{Z}{\sigma} \le \frac{y-kx}{\sigma}\right)\\
&= \Phi\left(\frac{y-kx}{\sigma} \right)
\end{align}

Hence $Y|X=x$ follows normal distribution with mean $kx$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

Comment: I guess my question is why the second equality holds since it is not obvious to me using the definition of the conditional density.

Comment: Do you mean why can we replace $X$ by $x$? We are already given that $X=x$ so we can use it. $P(kX+Z \le y |X=x)= \frac{Pr(kX+Z \le y , X=x) }{f_X(x)} =\frac{Pr(kx+Z \le y , X=x) }{f_X(x)}= \frac{Pr(kx+Z \le y)f_X(X=x) }{f_X(x)}=P(kx+Z \le y)$

Comment: $f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}{(x,y)}}{f_X(x)}=\frac{f_{X,Z}(x,y-kx)}{f_X(x)}=\frac{f_X(x)f_{Z}(y-kx)}{f_X(x)}=f_Z(y-kx)$. Recall that 
$f_Z(z)=\frac1{2\pi\sigma} \exp \left(-\frac{z^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)$, hence $f_Z(y-kx)=\frac1{2\pi\sigma} \exp \left(-\frac{(y-kx)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)$

Comment: Thanks a lot. The way you explain using conditional cumulative distribution makes sense since $p(kX + Z \leq y, X = x) = p(kx+Z \leq y, X = x)$  which is  straightforward and I can get my desired conclusion by taking derivative. However, I do not quite follow how to get $f_{X, Y}(x,y) = f_{X, Z}(x, y-kx)$.  Is that obvious? Sorry, I know I am asking too many questions here but I really want to understand it.

Comment: If we know that $X=x$ and $Y=y$, then from the definition $Y=kX+Z$, we can conclude that $Z=Y-kX=y-kx$ and $X=x$.